# How to model a continuous time stochastic process that is a positive constant but at random arrival times jumps to zero?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

How to model a continuous time process that is, at every instant, a positive constant (say, $δ > 0$) but at random arrival times jumps to zero? Let’s denote with ${N(t), t ≥ 0}$ the number of jumps from $δ$ to 0 in [0, t], and model it as a Poisson counting process with intensity parameter $η > 0$. That is, $dN(t)$ is $0$ or $1$.

[image: This figures captures what I am trying to model.]

My attempt is: 
$$dD(t)=\delta dt-\delta dN(t),$$
where $D(t)$ is the cumulative of the process.

Does this imply that, in a small time interval $[t,t+dt]$, with probability $\eta dt$, the random variable is $0$, but with probability $1-\eta dt$, it is $\delta$? Put together, then, the expectation is $$\eta dt (0)+(1-\eta dt)\delta=(1-\eta dt)\delta.$$

If I take the expectation of the first equation directly:
$$E[dD(t)]=\delta dt - \delta \eta dt=\delta(1-\eta)dt.$$

This is, however, inconsistent with the second equation.

So my question is (1) is my attempt correct? (2) if it is, in a small time interval, what is the probability it is $\delta$ vs. $0$, and (3) what is its expectation?

Comment: In a small positive finite time interval, it is almost always $\delta$, but may be $0$ a number of instantaneous times.  I would not try to use differentials here